# I want to print the last 2 strings present in each line in a file

Tags: regex, string, perl

**F1.txt**

```
boy a s b/b/b see

girl d e w/w/w day
```

**result**

F2.txt

```
b/b/b see

w/w/w day
```

Hello everyone,can you please help me out.I have a file f1.txt I want to print the last 2 strings present in each line in a file.Thanks in advance

Comment: Format your questions and show us your work.

Comment: "Last two Strings in each line" What do you mean by this? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do what you need

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $in, '<', 'f1.txt' or die $!;
open my $out, '>', 'f2.txt' or die $!;

while (<$in>) {
  my @fields = split;
  splice @fields, 0, @fields - 2;
  print $out "@fields\n";
}
```

**output**

```
b/b/b see

w/w/w day
```

Comment: Why to print blank lines and one word only lines?

Comment: @cdtits: I think it's more difficult to explain a choice *not* to print lines with less than two words. The question showed blank lines should be retained

Comment: It worked fine for me Borodin.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Don't know perl very well but to extract the wanted string from a line in any language this regexp would do:

```
\s([^\s]+\s[^\s]+)$
```

**EDIT:**

As someone stated that regex is tailored for that specific file format this one would be more flexible and get the last two strings separated by any number of spaces:

```
\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)$
```

Comment: Test your code. This insists on exactly one space between the last two words amnd one space before them. Also `/[^\s]/` is `/\S/`

Comment: I know @Borodin, but I was assuming he was using that input file format (like people usually do, they decide a file format and stick with that) so the regex was tailored for that scope.

Comment: The regex is not checking the first word but the ending of the string like the $ char states.. you should learn [regex](http://regexpal.com/). @Borodin

Comment: You have `\s` *before* the first word. *Try your code*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
perl -lane 'print "@F[-2,-1]" if $F[-2] && $F[-1];' f1.txt >f2.txt
```

Comment: Rhis prints nothing for empty lines or lines with one word

Comment: @Borodin: which is an undefined case, since the OP did not specify how that should be handled. Doesn't seem worth a downvote if there's no indication that it's not the desired behavior.

Comment: @DragonWraith, Actually, the example provided by the OP did have a blank line.

Comment: `if @F > 1` would be a saner check if you wanted to skip blank lines.